# Global method to create a link in view

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, codeigniter

I am developing a online shop, initially all the product links was like:

```
/index.php/shop/product/1
```

but then I wanted to change into

```
/index.php/shop/product/product-slug
```

Then I realize that I had to search to the entire project about where I put links for products and change.

The question is how can I make something like this in view:

```
<?php foreach($recomanded_products as $recomanded_product): ?>

     <a href="<?= $product_link ?>"><?= lang('comanda') ?></a>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

instead

```
<?php foreach($recomanded_products as $recomanded_product): ?>

     <a href="<?= site_url('shop/produs/'.$recomanded_product->slug_product) ?>"><?= lang('comanda') ?></a>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

so if I want to change the link to change only in one place.

Something like ruby on rails when you make <%= link_to 'Product', $product %>

Maybe a helper or to create from model the link?

I will tag also ruby on rails on this question, maybe a ruby developer comes with a logic.

Comment: Store the links in a database? - Heck, i'd recommend you store all your menu's / infrastructure links in a database

Comment: I don't think this is a good logic. Maybe a helper or from model to create the link?

Comment: But the problem is how `$recomanded_product->slug_product` is assigned to a `$product_link `.  `$recomanded_product` is avialble only after `foreach(..)` is encountered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a helper for this. create helper in `application/helpers/` as `linkview_helper.php` and in that

```
   <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    if(!function_exists('putLink'))
    {
        function putLink($value)
        {
           return site_url('shop/produs/'.$value);
        }
    }
```

now load your helper `linkview`. inorder to autorun this

```
  $autoload['helpers'] = array('linkview');
```

now use

```
 <?php foreach($recomanded_products as $recomanded_product): ?>
   <a href="<?= putLink($recomanded_product->slug_product) ?>"><?= lang('comanda') ?></a>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: And if I wan't to change `$recomanded_product->slug_product` from view in `$recomanded_product->id_product` I must change again in all project.

Comment: if you want so then you have to put your entire foreach loop in helper.

Comment: yes fine.. you can pass the object ; anyway you cannot skip an argument... :-)

Comment: Yes, this is true. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to create a helper class. I called it Linker in this example.

So you have really one place, where you can make changes, if you need. You could also add a param for language, or internal/external link and a lot more.

**Linker.php**

```
class Linker {
    /**
     * some more methods
     */
    public static function getInternalProduktLink( $product_id ) {
        // some rules for your linkpath
        $linkpath = "/index.php/shop/product/product-slug/";
        // result from your rules => $linkpath

        // maybe check if $product_id is an integer?
        $linkpath = "$linkpath/$product_id";

        return $linkpath;
    }

    public static function getExternalProduktLink( $product_id ) {
        // some rules for your linkpath
        // get your server url from somewhere
        $server = "http://www.example.com";
        $linkpath = "$server/index.php/shop/product/product-slug/";
        // result from your rules => $linkpath

        // maybe check if $product_id is an integer?
        $linkpath = "$linkpath/$product_id";

        return $linkpath;
    }
    /**
     * some more methods
     */
}

?>
```

In your template you can call it like this:

```
<a href="<?= Linker::getInternalProduktLink( $some_product_id) ?>"><?= lang('comanda') ?></a>
```

Comment: If I choose this method, inside getInternalProduktLink or getExternalProduktLink I must make a new query to get the product-slug from db.

Comment: if you need the `product-slug` you can pass it as parameter instead of `$product_id`

Comment: Yes, and again I must change in x places in my code. I found a solution and will come with an answer.

Comment: Ohh great idea, you created a class Linker, and have to change your code wherever you call it, how did you come to this decision? xD

Comment: Why to change my code wherever I call it? If I want to change my url for example to change `produs` to `item` I only change to class and not on 30 places on my website. Is this correct? And this is available only for products, for other items I create only a new function.

Comment: if you're using `Linker::somefunc` instead of `site_url()`you have to change `site_url()` to `Linker::somefunc`. Well you solution apart from the params and funtions you are calling is just a copy of my approach, but hey, that's OK

Answer (score 0):

I created a new helper

```
<?php

/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: sebastian
 * Date: 04.11.2015
 * Time: 10:44
 */
class Linker
{
    public static function PLink( $data ) {

        return site_url('shop/produs/'.$data->slug_produs);

    }
}
```

Then in view:

```
<?php foreach($recomanded_products as $recomanded_product): ?>

     <a href="<?= Linker::PLink($recomanded_product) ?>"><?= $produs->nume_produs ?></a>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Tick the solution and close the question :-)